# Question on foiling with vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Show that
$$\frac1{f}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})'=\frac1{f}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i'-n\bar{\mathbf{x}}\bar {\mathbf{x}}').$$

I need this to understand an example in my textbook on Hotelling's $T^2$ but I can't figure out how they get this result. I imagine it's quite trivial but I can't seem to figure it out..

Edit, my textbook is using this result to simplify computation. Otherwise you need to sum a lot of vectors :/

Comment: Is that a dot product in between?

Comment: Yes. The book doesn't show the notation but it is meant to be the dot product

Comment: As a teacher, I believe that the reason you had any trouble with this at all is that somebody taught you “foil” instead of getting you to understand the principle of distributivity.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, any bilinear form $\left<-,-\right>$ obeys FOIL (For those who haven't taken algebra in the US, this stands for *first, outer, inner, last*).
Given vectors $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$:
\begin{align*}
\left<a+b,c+d\right> &= \left<a,c+d\right> + \left<b,c+d\right> \\
    &= \left<a,c\right> + \left<a,d\right> + \left<b,c\right> + \left<b,d\right> \\
\end{align*}
If, in addition, the form is symmetric, you can combine terms.  For instance,
\begin{align*}
    \left<x-y,x-y\right> &= \left<x,x\right> - \left<x,y\right> - \left<y,x\right> + \left<y,y\right>
\\  &= \left<x,x\right> - 2 \left<x,y\right> + \left<y,y\right>
\end{align*}

For the identity you're working on, the key is the identity $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{x}_j = n \bar{\mathbf {x}}$.  We have
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{x}_i - \bar{\mathbf{x}})(\mathbf{x}_i - \bar{\mathbf{x}})'
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i' - \mathbf{x}_i\bar{\mathbf{x}}' - \bar{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}_i' + \bar{\mathbf{x}}\bar{\mathbf{x}}'\right)
  \\&= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i' - \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i \bar{\mathbf{x}}' - \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}_i' + n \bar{\mathbf{x}}\bar{\mathbf{x}}'
\end{align*}
By the distributive property,
\begin{align*}
   \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i \bar{\mathbf{x}}'
  &=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i\right) \bar{\mathbf{x}}' = n \bar{\mathbf {x}}\bar{\mathbf{x}}' \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}_i'
&= \bar{\mathbf{x}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i'\right)
 = \bar{\mathbf{x}}(n\bar{\mathbf{x}}') = n \bar{\mathbf{x}}\bar{\mathbf{x}}'
\end{align*}
So the middle two terms combine with the last, and the result is proved.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\text{right: } (a+b)(c+d) & = ab+ad+bc+bd \\
\text{wrong: } (a+b)(c+d) & = ab+ad+cb+bd
\end{align}
This second one is wrong except in cases where it doesn't matter in which order you multiply; so it is correct if these are numbers but wrong if they are matrices.

The more basic fact is the distributive law:
\begin{align}
\text{right: } p(q+r) & = pq + pr \\
\text{wrong: } p(q+r) & = qp+rp
\end{align}

Now apply the distributive law **three times:**
\begin{align}
& (a+b)(c+d) \\[10pt]
= {} & (\cdots\cdots)(c+d) \\[10pt]
= {} & (\cdots\cdots)c + (\cdots\cdots) d  & & \text{(first application of the distributive law)} \\[10pt]
= {} & (a+b)c + (a+b)d \\[10pt]
= {} & ac + bc + (a+b)d & & \text{(second application of the distributive law)} \\[10pt]
= {} & ac + bc + ad + bd & & \text{(third application of the distributive law)}
\end{align}
In other words "FOIL" is a derived law rather than a primitive law. The associative law is primitive in this argument.